# Jquery sortable on dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I have a rails 4 app that has nested fields and I'm trying to get jQuery sortable working on products.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" id='products'>
   <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'product_fields', f: builder %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

and my product_fields partial looks like:

```
<div class='product'>
   test
</div>
```

and my jQuery looks like:

```
$('#products').sortable({
   items: ".product"
});
$('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(e) {
   var regexp, time;
   time = new Date().getTime();
   regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
   $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));

   return e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically, what's happening is that I already have one `.product` on the page, when it is loaded (via Rails). Then when you click a button I have some jQuery that generates identical `.product` divs. But only the first `.product` (the one that is created by Rails server-side) is the only one that is sortable.

Comment: The problem looks to be `sortable` is not called for dynamically added elements.  You could trigger an event which calls `sortable` in the jQuery code which generates those identical `.product` divs.  Can you update your question with the code that inserts these new divs.

Comment: @Vee, Sure, just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialize sortable each time you add a new .product so that it picks up the new addition.. which makes sense anyway, as you won't need to sort the initial single .product

after...

```
$(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
```

put..

```
$('#products').sortable({
  items: ".product"
});
```

or..

```
$('#products').sortable('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't change anything?

Comment: hmm... have you tried... $('#products').sortable( "refresh" ); ?

Comment: I tried that too before, it didn't work. But I figured out the problem, for some reason the new .products were not being added to the  #products div, they were being added to to the next div down the DOM. Thanks anyways!

Comment: DOH! yeah that would do it! Np!