# Sortable div in dynamic add+remove div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add sortable option in dynamic add+remove div

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.added:last').after('<div class="addedline col-md-12"><div class="row"><div class="sort d-flex align-items-center"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label>Item Name</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><label>Description</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Size</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Quantity</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 remove"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Remove" /></div></div></div>');
});
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="added col-md-12">
    <span class="add"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="+ Add Items" /></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its work in stand alone div but not in optionbox

Comment: In your current code snippet `jquery-ui.min.js` needs to be added after `jquery.min.js`. May be that's the issue you are facing actually.

Comment: noted that. but i need help to make added items sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your code a bit

You have to add `sortable` on each created div

Do like below:-

```
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.added:last').append('<div class="addedline col-md-12"><div class="row"><div class="sort d-flex align-items-center"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label>Item Name</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><label>Description</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Size</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Quantity</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 remove"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Remove" /></div></div></div><br>');
  $('.optionBox').sortable({
    items: ".addedline"
  });
});
$('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/vh1y5cek/

reference taken:- [Jquery sortable on dynamically created divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726473/jquery-sortable-on-dynamically-created-divs)

Note:- you need to change remove code like below:-

```
$('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.addedline').remove();
});
```

Comment: @Tat  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You just need to remove the older script which is a version of `1.12.0`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.added:last').after('<div class="addedline col-md-12"><div class="row"><div class="sort d-flex align-items-center"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"><label>Item Name</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><label>Description</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Size</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12"><label>Quantity</label><input class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 remove"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Remove" /></div></div></div>');
});
$('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="added col-md-12">
    <span class="add"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="+ Add Items" /></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: noted that. but i need help to make added items sortable.

Comment: sorting based on what value? and where?

Comment: after add multiple items, items can be drag/sort to top and bottom